# Redirect external http connection within internal network

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nginx, asp.net-core, nginx-reverse-proxy

**Network structure**
[image]

When a user connects from the internet, he gets always forwarded to container A.

The containers all contain asp.net core mvc applications.

**Problem** 
I want, based on a decision which happens within container A, to be able to redirect the client to container B or container C. These containers run on ports 5001 and 5002 which aren't published to the internet.

**What I tried**

- Different combinations of the asp.net [Redirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.redirect?view=aspnetcore-3.0) function
- The nginx upstram and proxy functionality (primary in a setup like [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html))

I tried to find some pass through functionality for asp.net core but couldn't find any.

Comment: A HTTP redirect will simply tell the client / browser to make another HTTP request to a new URL. If that URL isn't accessible, you cant do a redirect.

Comment: Well, you will have to setup nginx so it knows when a user wants to access container B or C, usually by assigning a url (like /containerB/) to the corresponding port (5001) and then you just have to redirect to /containerB/.

Comment: @Longoon12000 won't this result in the same problem as the redirect (pointed out by JohnathanBarclay)?

Comment: @91378246 by configuring nginx so that your containers are accessible, then no. As Johnathan says correctly, if the URL (eg. containers B and C) aren't accessible then you can not redirect to them (well, you can but you won't be able to access them). Hence why you must make them accessible. And if you only have a single port 80/443 for three different apps then you have to get nginx to figure out which port to forward to (to container A, B or C) by URL.

Comment: @Longoon12000 yes, but the problem is, that I want to pass every connection first through container A before forwarding it. Creating a location for /ContainerB/ will make it accessible from outside.

Comment: But explain how you want your users to access container B if container B is not accessible by users? That's paradox. If you want container B to be accessible then it has to be accessible.

Comment: The same way like a reverse proxy does it: By forwarding the request to the corresponding container.

Comment: And that's exactly what I'm suggesting you do.

Answer (score 0):

1) If all services have the same hostname and scheme(http/https), use relative paths

2) if no, configure nginx reverse proxy to provide for proxied apps following headers:

```
   proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
   Host $host:$server_port
```

Configure UseForwardedHeaders in asp applications

```
    services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.ForwardedHeaders =
            ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
        options.KnownNetworks.Clear();
        options.KnownProxies.Clear();
    });
    ....
    app.UseForwardedHeaders();
```

It will fill Request.Scheme and Request.Host with initial request, that was made by client
Redirect using this information

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: A link to documentation in Russian is probably not all that helpful for visitors who don't speak the language. I guess you can change `ru-ru` to `en-US` and hope Microsoft doesn't notice (they seem to have a policy to rename or remove anything people link to).